# What is a better way to drop rows based on column values quickly?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a better method to drop rows without iterating the conditions?

```
#Current method:
Drop_words = [a, b, c, d, e]
For i in drop_words:
      df = df [~df['column'].string.contains (i)
```

Comment: how about `df['column'].str.contains('|'.join(Drop_words))`

Comment: Amazing thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contains() also accepts regex.

```
df[~df['column'].str.contains("a|b|c|d|e", regex=True)]
```